# Why doesn't arrayList sort in java even after using collections.reverse()

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to sort a hashmap based on its values,

The way I am doing this is separating the keyset and valueset of the hashmap into two  arrayList
,then sorting the lists individually  and then adding the values in a new haspMap after some  comparison operations 
but for some reason collection.reverse(LIST), won't sort the list in descending order

Here is my code:

```
 public LinkedHashMap sortHashMapByValuesD(HashMap passedMap)
     {
        ArrayList <Integer>mapKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>(passedMap.keySet());
        ArrayList <Double>mapValues= new ArrayList<Double>(passedMap.values());
        Collections.reverse(mapValues);
        Collections.reverse(mapKeys);  //>>**Here the list won't sort for some reason**



        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>();

        Iterator valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
        while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
            Object val = valueIt.next();
            //System.out.println(val);
            Iterator keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
                Object key = keyIt.next();

                Double comp1 =(Double)passedMap.get(key);

                Double comp2 = (Double)val;

                if (comp1==comp2){

                    passedMap.remove(key);
                    mapKeys.remove(key);
                    sortedMap.put((Integer)key,(Double)val);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        return sortedMap;
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: collection.revers is used for reversing , not for sorting, also you concept of sorting the hashmap doesnt sound good to me :(

Comment: well I am trying to come up with something regarding the sorting of the map,

So basically I need to do sort then revere to sort the collection in descending order?

Comment: all you need to do is `Collections.sort(mapValues)`,then `Collections.reverse(mapValues)`, I think. Oh, and read the documentation of the methods you use, so you know what they do.

Comment: Yeah its working now like this 
  Collections.sort(mapValues);
   
     Collections.reverse(mapValues);

Comment: yeah my bad ,should had read .reverse() documentation, I just assumed it sorts in decending order

Comment: `==` compares object references, not their contents.  This means that two `Double` can contain the same value, but `==` will be false as they are different objects.

Comment: If `reverse()` did sort in descending order, it wouldn't help you because the `Double` and `Integer` would no longer match up as you would be sorting these independently.

Answer (score 1):

[HashMaps are hashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_map), not sorted.  In particular, `HashMap<K, V>` does not implement the `SortedMap<K, V>` interface.  If you want a map sorted by key, try `TreeMap`, or any other implementation of `SortedMap`.

Maps sorted by index are not commonly requested and not directly supported within rt.jar.  You can't even call them `SortedMaps`, since a map sorted by values is (almost) certainly *not* sorted by keys.  While you can implement a map that is sorted by value, you may find that a slightly different approach fits the bill while sticking to the philosphies of java's collections framework.  Try creating a map-backed collection or iterator, that provides the ordering you require, and uses your original HashMap as its store.

A much simpler solution would be to

```
Set<Double> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Double>(yourPreferredComparator);
sortedSet.addAll(passedMap.values());
```

However you would lose any duplicated values with this solution.

Comment: And then it will be sorted by its keys, not values.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is a map that keeps the insertion order, which is exactly what the OP is trying to do

Comment: Hmm,Thanks for you comments , for now the sorting method which I wrote is working after correcting the code 

maybe next time I would start of using treemap instead

Comment: TreeMap sorts based on index.  Gimme a minute to update my answer :)